How to implement Firewall Hardware for Ethernet
I'm doing a research on implementing firewall hardware but surprisingly couldn't find any guidance using Google.
Here's my understanding:

How is firewall implemented? Any chips or kit solely designed for doing firewall function? Would this firewall possibly contain a dedicated MCU just for firewall?
Any guidance please? My focus is identifying hardware that can be incorporated into a circuit design.
Link to KSZ9893R.

It is usually a software program running on the SOC.


Would this firewall possibly contain a dedicated MCU just for firewall?

Yes, a firewall could contain a dedicated MCU for performing specific functions, especially in embedded applications where monitoring network traffic or applying simple filtering rules is sufficient. This MCU would typically handle packet inspections and rule enforcement and offload cryptographic operations to a co-processor if needed. With your example, Microchip or NXP would provide dedicated MCUs that have specific cryptographic engines that would specifically offload encryption/decryption tasks.
At the end of the day, the firewall itself is software driven in a real-time operating systems that is coded to contain numerous rules, policies, packet inspection, traffic filters, and so forth. When you're talking about "hardware" firewalls, you're really talking about a dedicated chip that is coded to do all of this. There's no conventional logic gate or memory design that provides a firewall automatically for you because the application of a firewall greatly varies between various network infrastructures.

From a hardware perspective, it's likely to look more like this:

The firewall (and routing, if needed) would be software running on the SBC.
The switch chip you've selected has only three ports, which seems like kind of an odd choice, unless you're sure you really only need two that are externally available (one would be used to talk to the SBC).
For the SBC, you can choose a general purpose computer like a Raspberry Pi, or you can find a number of router boards that (for example) use a RPi compute module. The big advantage of these is that most intended specifically for routing will including at least two Ethernet ports, one to connect to the outside world, and for your internal devices that are protected by the firewall.
The software on the SBC can be something like a fairly vanilla Linux distro, or something like OpenWRT that's specifically written for use in router/gateway/firewall use. The latter tend to be a bit less versatile, but quite a bit easier to get up and running.
